# can encryption code be stolen?

Tags: c#

I want to create an encryption software , I want to know can hacker find a password for a encrypted file ?

Comment: That all depends on your encryption software doesn't it?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is very unclear what you want to ask.

Comment: of course there is every possible way

Comment: Of Course there is a possible way.Just Don't create your own algorithm.PLease follow this link  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/rc4csharp.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is : If there's a reward that's worth it then someone with enough resources can crack it.

**Do not create your own algorithm. I repeat do not create your own.**

Use an existing library. Many many millions have gone into getting this has difficult to break as possible and unless you have a educational interest in learning how to create them I would strongly urge you to reconsider and use an off the shelf package.

Chances are any algo you come up will be easily broken as crackers have many advanced tools to hand.

**I repeat do not create your own.**

Please see this question for more info. [What techniques do you use when writing your own cryptography methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118374/what-techniques-do-you-use-when-writing-your-own-cryptography-methods)

Comment: Do you know any good algorithm ?

Comment: start here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C#, probably yes. Anybody can look at a .NET app's source code through Reflector. Using that, one can reverse engineer your encryption algorithm.

If ever you are going to use other languages, lets say some which are not easy to decompile. Decent crackers can debug your program and look into how the encryption is done, through debugging. So, the answer is still Yes.

If you're gonna use C#, or any .NET language, obfuscate your code using an obfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. He can:

- guess it
- see it written down somewhere
- ask the user for it
- discover it by analysing the behaviour of the algorithm
- convince the user to change the password to one he knows

You need to design your software and the way it's used to make these as hard as possible. Not all of the above can be solved in software.

Answer (score 0):

Erm... Well... What do you want to know? HOW a hacker can find a password or IF a hacker can find a password. Considering this, make yourself clear and rephrase your question.

First, check out what encryption actually means. There are a lot of possibilities to encrpyt a {file, string, data, whatever}. An important question is: when does your data become invalid? If it is of no use anymore after one week then you do not need a strong encryption, maybe you can write something from scratch. If it still must be encrypted (undecrypted, unhacked) after like two years, you should use an encryption technique like RSA which has its foundation in mathematics and thus has been proven to be unhackable in a time that could give a hacker an advantage by having access to your data.

My answer is based on these two facts: unless the cracker has access to a network of thousands of hosts or a quantum computer, RSA should do the trick.

Peace